# how to get values from HTTP Response to Excel with VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, http, web-scraping

I need your little help to get stock value(corresponding to stock name) from the HTTP Response I got. Received Response is in form of HTML, of which i put some part as code is too long. downwards I have mention the VBA Code i am using but it is showing error. Please anyone help me..!!
Note: Stock Name and Values are present in "Input type"(line 5 from down)

```
<!--    <table align="left">
    <tr>
    <td> -->
        <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 110%;">
          <table border="0" align="left" width="688" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="table_style table_111111" id="data_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table_header"> 
                        <td width="15" class="center_align"><strong></strong></td>
                        <td width="50" class="left_align"><strong>Security </strong></td>
                        <td width="20" class="center_align"><strong>ME</strong></td>
                        <td width="15" class="center_align"><strong>Exch Code</strong></td>
                        <td width="15" class="center_align"><strong>Tradesmart Trends</strong></td>
                        <td width="20" class="center_align"><strong>IT</strong></td>
                        <td width="50" class="center_align"><strong>Expiry Date</strong></td>
                        <td width="50" class="center_align"><strong>Strike Price</strong></td>
                        <td width="10" class="center_align"><strong>Opt Type</strong></td>
                        <td width="32" class="center_align"><strong>Open Price</strong></td>
                        <td width="40" class="center_align"><strong>Buy Price</strong></td>
                        <td width="32" class="center_align"><strong>Buy Vol</strong></td>
                        <td width="41" class="center_align"><strong>Sell Price</strong></td>
                        <td width="32" class="center_align"><strong>Sell Vol</strong></td>
                        <td width="41" class="center_align"><strong>Last Price</strong></td>
                        <td width="28" class="center_align"><strong>High Price</strong></td>
                        <td width="41" class="center_align"><strong>Low Price</strong></td>
                        <td width="25" class="center_align"><strong>O.I.</strong></td>
                        <td width="20" class="center_align"><strong>CAs</strong></td>
                        <td width="50" class="center_align"><strong> % Change</strong></td>
                        <td width="50" class="center_align"><strong>Net Change</strong></td>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

<input type='hidden' id='first_watch' name='first_watch' value='current'/><tr class='tinside'><td class="left_align"><input type=checkbox name="stkcode" value="1157(NN)EQ" onClick="checkCheck(4);"></td><td class="left_align">APOLLOTYRE</td><td class="center_align">NSE</td><td class="center_align">163</td><td class="center_align"><A style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #31B404; font-weight: bold;' HREF="/itrade/user/recognia.exe?action=access"  >Bullish</A></td><td class="center_align">EQ</td><td class="center_align">-</td><td class="center_align">0.00</td><td class="center_align">- </td><td class="center_align">201.00</td><td class="center_align">0.00</td><td class="center_align"></td><td class="center_align">199.50</td><td class="center_align">1,990</td><td class="center_align">199.50</td><td class="center_align">203.85</td><td class="center_align">198.50</td><td class="center_align">    0</td><td class="center_align">XD</td>  <td class="center_align">    0.00</td>  <td class="center_align">    0.00</td>  </tr><tr class='tinside'><td class="left_align"><input type=checkbox name="stkcode" value="2441(NN)EQ" onClick="checkCheck(5);"></td><td class="left_align">SUNPHARMA</td><td class="center_align">NSE</td><td class="center_align">3351</td><td class="center_align"><A style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #31B404; font-weight: bold;' HREF="/itrade/user/recognia.exe?action=access"  >Bullish</A></td><td class="center_align">EQ</td><td class="center_align">-</td><td class="center_align">0.00</td><td class="center_align">- </td><td class="center_align">454.90</td><td class="center_align">0.00</td><td class="center_align"></td><td class="center_align">431.25</td><td class="center_align">66,412</td><td class="center_align">431.25</td><td class="center_align">455.00</td><td class="center_align">426.45</td><td class="center_align">    0</td><td class="center_align">XD</td>  <td class="center_align">    0.00</td>  <td class="center_align">    0.00</td>  </tr></table>
</div>
<!--</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Here is the VBA Code. what I am Using to send POST Req to get stock value in response.

```
Dim cook As String, bodyk As String, xmlhttp As Object, response As String
Dim getcookres As String, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim document As Object

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
cook = Worksheets("Action").Range("X2").Value
bodyk = Worksheets("Action").Range("X1").Value


URL = "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/itrade/user/watch.exe?action=C"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "www.xxxxxxxx.com"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "700"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "max-age=0"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Origin", "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/itrade/user/watch.exe?action=C"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cook

xmlhttp.send bodyk

html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText

'Set document = html.getElementsByid("header").getElementsByid("container")(0).getElementsByClassName("table-responsive")(0).getElementsByid("first_watch")(1)

Set document = html.getElementsByClassName("tinside")
'Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML
Debug.Print document
Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = document.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
```

Comment: What is the error message? On which specific line? (Please don't refer to line numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css selectors to target the td elements

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#data_table tr.tinside td")
For i = 0 To nodeList.Length -1
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).innerText
Next
```

The whole table you can use id selector

```
Dim ele As Object
Set ele  = html.getElementById("data_table")
' then loop the tr tags and then the td tags
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but the code is able to get value of attribute like name, values, id etc.. I am not able to grab Text values falling under class. for example (in above given HTML Code) what I am trying to grab is something like.                                                             APOLLOTYRE, NSE, 163, bullish, EQ, 0.00, 201.00, 0.00, 199.50, 1990, 199.20, ......... Etc. will it be possible to grab every stock data as it is falling under **class**.

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr..!! I think This is what exactly I required... thanks once again..!!